# Flutter - InputDecoration border only when focused

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to Design a custom `TextFormField` and everything is working fine except that I only need to show a border when the `TextFormField` is focused (someone has tapped into it).

As I don't think that is possible I tried to change the color of the border, but it seems to me that this color can only be set through the `hintColor` of the theme. But as the `hintColor` also changes the color of the hint Text being displayed i can't use that.

```
final theme = Theme.of(context);

return new Theme(
  data: theme.copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
  child: TextFormField(
    autocorrect: false,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
      contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
      labelText: title,
    ),
    validator: this.validator,
    onSaved: (String newValue) {
      setMethod(newValue);
    },
  ),
);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is a property named `focusedBorder`, you can use and change it according to your needs, and also set the default border as `InputBorder.none`, example:

```
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return TextFormField(
        autocorrect: false,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
          filled: true,
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          labelText: widget.title,
        ),
        validator: widget.validator,
        onSaved: (String newValue) {},
      );
    }
```

**Update if you don't have the focusedBorder attribute**

```
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MyCustomTextField(
              title: "Testing 1",
            ),
            MyCustomTextField(
              title: "Testing 2",
            )
          ],
        ));
      }
    }

    class MyCustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
      final String title;
      final ValueChanged<String> validator;

      MyCustomTextField({this.title, this.validator});

      @override
      _MyCustomTextFieldState createState() => _MyCustomTextFieldState();
    }

    class _MyCustomTextFieldState extends State<MyCustomTextField> {
      var _focusNode = new FocusNode();

      _focusListener() {
        setState(() {});
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        _focusNode.addListener(_focusListener);
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        _focusNode.removeListener(_focusListener);
        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextFormField(
          autocorrect: false,
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            border: _focusNode.hasFocus
                ? OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue))
                : InputBorder.none,
            filled: true,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
            labelText: widget.title,
          ),
          validator: widget.validator,
          onSaved: (String newValue) {},
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I expected to be some kind of property like that, but in my class there is no `focusedBorder` property. So if I add it to my code of copy and paste yours, the IDE tells me that the parameter isn't defined. 

What version are you running? I just ran flutter upgrade again, but it still isn't there. Are you on some kind of pre release?

Comment: ohhh , hmm I'm using flutter master branch

Comment: ah, ok. I am on the beta branch. Is the master stable enough to work on it or are there often bugs that prevent further development? Because if there aren't I would probably switch.

Comment: omg, I totally forgot that i could simple work with the state here...
Thank you sooo much :)

Answer (score -1):

You can define custom input decoration, and than apply it by isFocused:

```
    InputDecorator(
          isFocused: _focusNode.hasFocus,
          decoration: customInputDecoration,
          child: ...
    )

 final InputDecoration customInputDecoration = InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      filled: true,
      fillColor: AppPalette.grey80.withOpacity(0.3),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
      focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppPalette.green70),
      ),
      disabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppPalette.grey60),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppPalette.grey40.withOpacity(0.3)),
      ),
      errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: AppPalette.red60)),
      focusedErrorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: AppPalette.red40)),
      errorText: widget.errorText,
      errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
      isCollapsed: true,
    );
```